# Is it possible that you have the same arrival time in CPU Scheduling?

Tags: operating-system

I have searched the internet for examples for the algorithms in cpu scheduling and I have never seen any examples with the same arrival time.

Is it possible to make the processes have the same arrival time?

For example:

Algorithm: Round Robin

Process ---- Arrival Time ----- Burst Time

P1 ----------------- 3 ------------------ 4 -----

P2 ----------------- 1 ------------------ 5 -----

P3 ----------------- 1 ------------------ 3 -----

Quantum = 1

What would be the gantt chart look like?

Comment: It depends on how many cpus do you have. Its fisically imposible if you have only one.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm so confused right now

Comment: Think that putting items in a queue is a secuencial task

Comment: Maybe you can find help here: https://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Of Course, multiple processes can have the same arrival time i.e the time they came for looking the CPU to execute them. And its the responsibility of the Processor to handle and schedule them accordingly as per the appropriate Scheduling Algorithms.

When the Arrival time for two or more processes are same, then the RR-Scheduling follows FCFS {First come first serve} approach. Here in Round robin scheduling with quantum = 1,  we have

[Gantt Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKNqK.jpg)

At time 0, no process 
At time 1 , we have P2 and P3 with P2 first then after a quantum RR executes P3, 
At time 3 we have all three processes with order P2,P3,P1 hence the RR-Algorithm will keep switching between them until they complete their execution (burst) time.
And we will get all executed at time 13.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make the processes have the same arrival time?

Yes, for normal definitions of "same time" (e.g. excluding "in the same Planck time quantum") it's possible for processes to have the same arrival time.

For an example, imagine if 100 tasks sleep until midnight. When midnight occurs a timer IRQ handler processes a list of tasks waiting to wake up and wakes up 100 tasks at the "same" time.

Now, for this example you could say that "same time" is stricter; and that the timer IRQ handler processes the list of tasks sequentially and adds them to scheduler's queues sequentially, and that it's only "almost at the same time". In this case it's still possible to have N CPUs running in parallel (with a different timer for each CPU) that happen to wake (up to) N tasks at the same time.